# How closely related are two parasites Giardia intestinalis and Trichomonas vaginalis?

Tags: evolution, phylogenetics, parasitology

How closely related (from the evolutional point of view) are parasites *Giardia intestinalis* and *Trichomonas vaginalis*? *Giardia* genome is about 12 Mb and its major cellular proceses are rather simple. The genome of *Trichomonas* is approximately 160 Mb. What about its cellular processes, is it also a 'minimalist'?

Answer (score 2):

Basically, [*Giarda*](http://tolweb.org/Fornicata/121182) is a an *Excavates* while *Trichomonas* is a [*Cercozoa*](http://tolweb.org/Cercozoa/121187) meaning a *Rhizaria* (*Chromealveolates* in the broad sense as noticed by @har-wradim in the comments (now deleted) because Cercozoa are neither *Chromista* nor *alveolata*). Because the very basis of the tree of eukaryotes is still unresolved ([eukaryotes](http://tolweb.org/Eukaryotes/3)), the most recent common ancestor of these two species is just an old eukaryote! In other words, these two species are not more closely related than are related a cat and a chestnut tree!

The links yield to Tolweb.org which shows you the phylogenetic tree and allows you to explore the relationships between organisms. Have a look to eukaryote tree especially to see the positions of the *Rhizaria* and *Cercozoa*.

Comment: One more point: While *Giardia* and *Trichomonas* both lack mitochondria, the former has mitosomes and the latter has hydrogenosomes. Mitosome has the most reduced functionality

Comment: Be careful though that Tolweb is not always very up-to-date.